# "Ich denke" oder "Ich dachte"?

Tags: usage

> »Sie sind aus Bremen, oder?« [fragte der Spieß.]
>   »Ja.« [sagte Frank Lehmann.]
>   »Wohnen da und so weiter?«
>   »Ja.«
>   »Da haben Sie aber Schwein gehabt, Lehmann. Ihre Versetzung ist heute gekommen. Sie werden nach Bremen versetzt, zum Nachschub. Mann, haben Sie ein Schwein. Das hätte auch Bayern sein können, oder was weiß ich.«
> [...  ]
>   Der Spieß schaute wieder auf seine Papiere. »Lettow-Vorbeck-Kaserne«, las er vor. »Kennen Sie die?«
>   »Nein, weiß nicht«, sagte Frank.
>   »**Ich denke,** Sie sind aus Bremen.«
>   »Ja«, sagte Frank giftig. »Aber ich habe mich früher für Kasernen noch nicht so doll interessiert.«

Der Gebrauch von "Ich denke" in der obigen Passage aus *Neue Vahr Süd* (von Sven Regener) hat mich überrascht, denn ich würde vielleicht wegen meiner Muttersprache, Englisch, denken, dass "Ich dachte" richtig wäre. Ist "Ich denke" immer richtig/idiomatisch in dieser Situation, oder ist "Ich dachte"/"Ich habe gedacht" auch möglich?

Ich hoffe, dass die Natur der Situation, die ich erwähne, klar ist, aber falls nicht, meine ich die Situation, in der der andere dir etwas sagt, was dich eine deiner Annahmen in Frage stellen lässt. Im obigen Abschnitt wird es spöttisch gemeint, weil der Spieß schon weißt, dass Frank aus Bremen ist, aber ich weiß nicht, ob das was ausmacht.

Comment: Wären denn im Englischen nicht auch alle drei Zeitformen möglich?

Comment: @tofro: Grammatikalisch zwar schon, aber in dieser Situation (angenommen, dass ich sie richtig verstehe) müsste man "I thought you were from Bremen" sagen. Was Sinn macht, denn der Spott besteht darin, dass der Spieß ausdrückt, dass er falsch liegen musste, als er vor ein paar Sekunden glaubte, dass Frank aus Bremen ist, da Frank diese Kaserne in Bremen nicht kennt. Also glaubt der Spieß jetzt anders als davor, daher "I thought" auf Englisch, und "I think you're from Bremen" ginge gar nicht, wäre ganz verwirrend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alles ist hier richtig.

- *Ich denke...* da denkt er eben jetzt
- *Ich dachte...* da hat er bis gerade eben gedacht
- *Ich habe gedacht...* bis grade

Perfekt ist möglicherweise die eher gebräuchliche Version. Da viele, vor allem oberdeutsche Dialekte (wir wissen nicht, wo die Szene spielt, der Spieß kann durchaus aus Bayern sein) andere Zeitformen der Vergangenheit gar nicht kennen.

Comment: Tofro, danke, aber entgeht mir was? Ich dachte, das Ziel des Spieß ist zu äußern, dass er in der Vergangenheit etwas gedacht hat (Frank ist aus Bremen), was er aber jetzt wegen der neuen Information (Frank kennt die Bremer Kaserne nicht) nicht mehr denkt. Daher meine Verwirrung... Meinst du, dass auch "ich denke" diese Bedeutung hat?

Comment: Müsste er fragen, wenn er es nicht mehr dächte? Hätte er tatsächlich komplett aufgehört, zu denken, Frank wäre aus Bremen, wäre doch die Frage überflüssig, oder?

Comment: Ich bin bei "Ich denke, [...]" auch stutzig geworden. Wenn ich es mir aber ohne Pause nach dem "Ich denke" innerlich vorsage, funktioniert es. Als Norddeutscher (Südniedersachse) wäre für mich "Ich dachte, [...]" intuitiv richtig, "Ich denke, [...]" auch möglich, und die Perfektform sehr ungebräuchlich bis falsch.

Comment: @Raketenolli Für einen Süddeutschen hört sich sowohl Präsens als auch Präteritum eher "geschraubt" an - Perfekt wäre perfekt.

Comment: Tofro, spielt der Spott überhaupt eine Rolle, oder wäre es anders, wenn Frank sagen würde, "Ich bin aus Berlin," (nach er schon "Ich bin aus Bremen" gesagt hat), was den Spieß wirklich dazu bringen würde, seinen früheren Gedanken zu bezweifeln?

Comment: Nein, ich glaube nicht - der Spott wirkt sich meiner Meinung nach nicht auf die Formulierung aus - Die wäre genau gleich. Du musst bedenken, dass das Deutsche bei der Zeitenfolge **wesentlich** weniger pingelig ist als das Englische - wir benutzen auch das Präsens als Futur und das Perfekt als Präteritum, wenn uns danach ist.

Comment: Tofro, ok, vielen Dank, aber um einen Stresstest mal zu machen, macht es was aus, wenn der Fehler 100% klar ist? Also geht es nicht mehr um Zweifel, wie in den vorherigen Beispielen, sondern um Gewissheit. "Entschuldigung, wo sind die Fertigpizzen?" "Wie sollte ich das wissen? Ich arbeite in diesem Laden nicht." "Ach sorry! Ich denke, Sie sind Angestellter." Geht das auch genauso klar?

Comment: In diesem (anderen) Beispiel machst du klar, dass der Frager jetzt sehr sicher nicht mehr denkt - "Ach sorry! Ich denke, Sie sind Angestellter" macht sehr klar, dass der Frager aufgehört hat, das zu denken. Präsens wäre also zumindestens unlogisch und es muss "Ich dachte/habe gedacht, sie sind (wären) Angestellter" heißen.

Answer (score -1):

- **Ich denke.**
  Diese Zeitform heißt *Präsens* oder *Gegenwart.* Damit kann man unter bestimmten Bedingungen Ereignisse zu allen möglichen Zeiten beschreiben (Vergangenheit, Gegenwart, Zukunft), aber die grundlegende Funktion dieser Zeitform besteht darin, etwas zu beschrieben, das genau zu dem Zeitpunkt geschieht, in dem der Satz ausgesprochen wird.

  Dem kurzen Text entnehme ich, dass der Spieß während der ganzen Zeit, in der er Frank kennt, glaubt, er sei aus Bremen. Also glaubt er es auch in genau jenem Zeitpunkt, in dem er den Satz sagt. Daher ist die Verwendung der Gegenwart völlig korrekt und in dieser Situation auch die beste Wahl.
- **Ich dachte.**
  Diese Zeitform heißt *Präteritum* und sie hat mehrere deutsche Namen. In Deutschland heißt diese Zeitform *»unvollendete Vergangenheit«, »Nachvergangenheit«, »Imperfekt«* oder *»1. Vergangenheit.«* In Österreich ist der übliche Name für diese grammatische Zeitform *»Mitvergangenheit«.*

  Diese Zeitform wird verwendet um Ereignisse zu beschrieben, die in der Vergangenheit geschehen sind und keine Auswirkung auf die Gegenwart haben. Wenn jemand sagt *»Ich heiratete Renate«* dann kann man aus der Verwendung des Präteritums schließen, dass diese Ehe nicht mehr besteht. Wäre die Ehe noch aufrecht, würde man das Perfekt verwenden und sagen:  *»Ich habe Renate geheiratet«.* (Es gibt auch andere Gründe für die Verwendung des Perfekt, siehe weiter unten.)

  Wenn der Spieß sagen würde *»Ich dachte, sie sind aus Bremen«,* dann kann man daraus schließen, dass er das zu dem Zeitpunkt, als der den Satz sagte, bereit etwas anderes für wahr hielt (nämlich, dass Frank aus einer anderen Stadt stammt). Der kurze zitierte Text lässt aber vermuten, dass der Spieß sehr wohl die ganze Zeit über dachte, Frank sei aus Bremen. Daher wäre es falsch, das Präteritum zu verwenden.
- **Ich habe gedacht**
  Diese Zeitform heißt *Perfekt* und hat ebenfalls mehrere deutsche Namen. In Deutschland heißt diese Zeitform *»vollendete Gegenwart«, »Vorgegenwart«* oder *»2. Vergangenheit«.* Der gängige Begriff in Österreich ist *»Vergangenheit«.*

  Das ist die bevorzugte Zeitform für schriftliche Erzählungen. Wenn man einen Roman liest, wird die Handlung meist in dieser Zeitform wiedergegeben. Davon ausgenommen sind Dialoge, weil Dialoge ja gesprochene Sprache wiedergeben sollen, und für gesprochenes Deutsch gelten andere Tempus-Regel als für die Schilderungen in Erzählungen.

  Das Perfekt wird außerhalb von Büchern verwendet um Ereignisse zu beschrieben, die in der Vergangenheit liegen und dort auch abgeschlossen wurden, aber Auswirkungen auf die Gegenwart haben (siehe oben: *er heiratete* ↔︎ *er hat geheiratet*). Alles, was im Perfekt ausgedrückt wird, signalisiert also eine Verbindung der Vergangenheit zur Gegenwart, drückt aber auch aus, dass die Handlung selbst nicht mehr in der Gegenwart fortdauert.

  Beispiele:

  - Präteritum: »Ich wohnte 20 Jahre lang in Wien.«
    Es gab eine Zeit, in der ich in Wien gewohnt habe, aber diese Zeit ist vorbei und beeinflusst mein heutiges Leben nicht mehr.
  - Perfekt: »Ich habe 20 Jahre lang in Wien gewohnt.«
    Ich habe in der Vergangenheit in Wien gewohnt, habe meinen Wohnsitz jetzt aber woanders. Trotzdem habe ich jetzt noch eine Verbindung zu Wien, die mein Leben beeinflusst (z.B. Freundeskreis mit dem man noch in Kontakt ist)
  - Präsens: »Ich wohne seit 20 Jahren in Wien.«
    Ich bin vor 20 Jahren in diese Stadt gezogen und wohne seitdem dort. Ich wohne auch jetzt dort.

  Wenn der Spieß sagen würde *»Ich habe gedacht, Sie sind aus Bremen«,* dann bedeutet das, dass der Spieß zu dem Zeitpunkt, in dem er den Satz sagt, etwas anderes glaubt (nämlich, dass Frank in einer anderen Stadt wohnt). Es bedeutet aber auch, dass sein früherer Glaube über Franks Wohnsitz, auf die gegenwärtige Situation Einfluss hat. Beispielsweise könnte diese frühere Vermutung der Grund dafür sein, dass der Dialog zwischen dem Spieß und Franz überhaupt geführt wird. Wenn der restliche Text diese Interpretation zulässt, wäre *»Ich habe gedacht«* eine mögliche Option. Aber wie schon mehrfach erwähnt: Der wiedergegebene kurze Text lässt die Interpretation, dass der Spieß glaubt, Franz würde aus einer anderen Stadt als Bremen stammen, nicht zu. Daher wäre hier auch das Perfekt die falsche Zeitform.

---

Zu Präteritum und Perfekt gibt es noch einiges zu ergänzen: Diese Zeitformen werden in gesprochenem Deutsch und in geschriebenem Deutsch unterschiedlich verwendet. Es gibt auch den sogenannten *oberdeutschen Präteritumsschwund.* Damit ist gemeint, dass in dem Gebiet, in dem oberdeutsche Dialekte gesprochen werden (im Wesentlichen: Schweiz, Österreich, Baden Württemberg, Bayern) das Präteritum in der gesprochenen Sprache durch das Perfekt ersetzt wird. Da Österreich vollständig in dieser Region liegt, gilt das in Österreich nicht nur für Dialekte, sondern auch für die Standardsprache. Das ist auch der Grund dafür, dass in österreichischen Schulbüchern das Perfekt ganz einfach nur *»Vergangenheit«* genannt wird. Dies weiter zu vertiefen, würde aber den Rahmen dieser Antwort sprengen.

<sub>*(Leider habe ich so gut wie kein Wissen über die Grammatik der schweizerischen Standardvarietät der deutschen Sprache und kann daher darüber nichts sagen.)*</sub>

Comment: Danke. Wie ich @tofro geschrieben habe, ich verstehe etwas nicht. Deine Antwort erklärt mir, dass die drei Formen unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben, aber angesichts des Kontextes (den habe ich in meiner Frage jetzt verlängert), kommt es mir vor, dass der Text die Interpretation doch zulässt, vielleicht sogar fordert, dass der Spieß nicht mehr denkt (oder zumindest spöttisch tut, als ob er nicht mehr denkt), dass Frank aus Bremen ist.

Comment: Liebe Downvoter, es wäre hilfreicher, wenn die Downvotes eklärt würden.